# D3 v4 Multi line chart Brush Issue NaN when moving brush

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been working on D3 v4 multi line with brush axis. The graph plots correctly with multi lines in it , however when I am trying to move the brush, D3 is throwing me an `NaN` error.

Attached is the below link in blockbuilder.org:

http://blockbuilder.org/mhaneef50673/0b7304759ccbc1e3ba8cf4aa58e56695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `brush.extent()` as a getter? You have to change the scale's domain instead, using `d3.event.selection`, like this:

```
xFocus.domain(d3.event.selection === null ? xContext.domain() : 
    d3.event.selection.map(xContext.invert, xContext));
```

Also, you have to pass `d.values` to the line generator, not just `d`.

Here is your updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/cb7048512af17ed3683e79637eee40d7/9d8d7945bbcb39dabb568dd68247316d2ace5ac3

Comment: WooW !! That is brilliant .. thanks a lot .. Once more issue/question.. right now the first chart is showing the entire data, how to restrict the first chart to show only few dates and using the brush i can traverse through the entire data set ?

Comment: As this is another issue, feel free to post it as a new question. Answering questions made in the comments is complicated, because we have to edit the answer, which makes it awkward for future readers.

Comment: let me add a new question and post you the link :)

Comment: hey i could add a question only in next 90 minutes .. Could you please help me with my question below,

1. I want to show minimum values(say 5) in the axes and need to traverse through the entire dataset using brush axis
2. Also when traversing through the data set using the brush, the line doesnt seem to hide under the axis.

Comment: gerardo Furtado. I have edited the question for more clarity on few more items i need it urgently .. Would request your help on the same .. thanks :(

Comment: @user2159399 please **do not** edit questions that already have answers to do another questions. I rolled it back. As I told you, please post a *new* question instead.

Comment: Apologies.. I am in desperate need of a solution. Hence the edit .. Alright added a new question.. here we go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643731/d3-js-v4-multi-line-chart-axis-issue :)

Comment: :) awaiting your response :)